# How to concatenate string from list in one string and show in textarea in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have passed Python list to template like

```
l=['text','there is no salary','I need alcohol','and I want be high']
```

I have inside template **textarea** with **id="raw"**. How to concatenate all elements from list l in one string and show in textarea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<textarea>{{ l|join:"" }}</textarea>
```

See the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#filters) on template filters